i2c device not giving output when connecting to raspberry pi 4b
I am connecting i2c device (for displaying results)  to raspberry pi 4b using GPIO pins all the connection is okay from raspberry pi to i2c display. and the address of i2c device i am putting correctly, but i am not getting the display on i2c device. while not running the device blue light comes out through i2c device but when i run the program which is suppose to give display at the device , the blue light goes off , kindly help, I on the i2c through raspi config
While running a test code
from luma.core.interface.serial import i2c
from luma.oled.device import ssd1306
from luma.core.render import canvas
from PIL import ImageFont


try:
    serial = i2c(port=1, address=0x27)  # or 0x3D
    device = ssd1306(serial)
    print("I2C device initialized successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to initialize I2C device: {e}")


def display_message():
    try:
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            draw.rectangle(device.bounding_box, outline="white", fill="black")
            draw.text((10, 10), "1", fill="white")
        print("Message displayed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to draw on display: {e}")


display_message()

its giving output that i2c device initialized successfully and message displayed succesfully , but there is nothing output on the i2c device , just it blinks sometimes

I have run your code on a Pi 4b under Bookworm (and also on a Pi 3b under Raspbian), and it displays perfectly on the 1306 OLED. If I put in the wrong I2C address or if I disconnect the SDA or CLK pins or fail to enable I2C in the preferences it obviously fails, but the code prints out that it has failed. So if you are getting confirming messages, it has to be that the OLED is faulty. I have a number of 1306 OLEDs, and a couple of them fail - but they show snow on the screen, which is not what you are getting. But at least I can confirm that there is nothing wrong with the code.

Just use the kernel driver for that device and have a regular frame buffer or DRM device. No need to reinvent the wheel, really. With that you may use normal SDL (and python SDL binding respectively).
